# Firebase OTP received, but not verified when I entered received OTP

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Please help me anyone solve this issue. I have received OTP successfully but OTP is not verified when I renter the received OTP.

```
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNum, 30L /*timeout*/, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this, new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    VerificationCode = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode().toString();
                }
                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    Toasty.error(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

**OTP verification**

```
relative_layout_confirm_top_login_activity.setOnClickListener(v->{
        if(otp_edit_text_login_activity.getText().toString().length()<6){
            Toasty.error(this, "The verification code you have been entered incorrect !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            if (otp_edit_text_login_activity.getText().toString().trim().equals(VerificationCode.toString().trim())){
                String photo = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg" ;
                signUp(phoneNum,phoneNum,"null".toString(),"phone",photo);
            }else{
                Toasty.error(this, "The verification code you have been entered incorrect !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you're actually verifying the OTP code entered?

Comment: I have updated snippet please check it @MBD